# Database Configuration In DB2 and Oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, configuration

What is the equivalent in Oracle for these Db2 configuration parameters?

```
Interval for checking deadlock (ms)         (DLCHKTIME) 
Lock timeout (sec)                        (LOCKTIMEOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, there are no equivalent settings.  Checking for deadlocks is something that happens automatically, there is no setting that configures when that checking is done.  Oracle generally has no system-level timeout for locks.  You can set `DISTRIBUTED_LOCK_TIMEOUT` but that only affects how long a distributed transaction would wait for a lock to be acquired, it has no impact on non-distributed transactions.  Beyond that, a session will wait for a lock indefinitely unless the session requesting the lock specifies a timeout (i.e. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE WAIT n`).